# How to diagnose a Docker Image that runs locally on docker-compose but not when i pull it down from the published registry

Tags: docker

I have a `docker-compose` file on my localhost machine which builds/starts a number of images. Some of them from Docker Hub and some of them built locally from various folders. It's works 100% great.

So then I commit the code and CI/CD kicks off which builds/publishes the images to Azure Container Registry.

When I then try to test it out locally on a different machine (just to make sure I'm pulling the images from my private ACR) it downloads and runs .. but exists ASAP.

Did it build right? I checked the CI/CD (Azure DevOps) and it *looks* ok in the build log steps...

```
Step 20/25 : FROM build AS publish
 ---> d113b9619e30
Step 21/25 : RUN dotnet publish src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/Accounts.Api.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app
 ---> Running in b36c1dd08489
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.450+ga8dc7f1d34 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Core.RavenDb -> /src/src/Core/Core.RavenDb/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/Hornet.Core.RavenDb.dll
  Core.Api -> /src/src/Core/Core.Api/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/Hornet.Core.Api.dll
  Core.Storage -> /src/src/Core/Core.Storage/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/Hornet.Core.Storage.dll
  Core -> /src/src/Core/Core/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/Hornet.Core.dll
  Accounts.Api -> /src/src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/Hornet.Accounts.Api.dll
  Accounts.Api -> /app/
Removing intermediate container b36c1dd08489
 ---> 875cf63adca5

Step 22/25 : FROM base AS final
 ---> 33771ffc2cd4
Step 23/25 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in b26b4905b7ec
Removing intermediate container b26b4905b7ec
 ---> 73d01509c3e7
Step 24/25 : COPY --from=publish /app .
 ---> 7e7e23ae420c
Step 25/25 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Hornet.Accounts.Api.dll"]
 ---> Running in 907bcae5d89f
Removing intermediate container 907bcae5d89f
 ---> 946840d2393f

Successfully built 946840d2393f
Successfully tagged <snip>.azurecr.io/hornet/accounts.api:latest
```

so .. I'm not too sure how to debug the image that is published, to check to see what it contains.

I tried to do an interactive mode, but that didn't do anything.

```
docker run -it <snip>.azurecr.io/hornet/accounts.ap sh
```

but that just exited to the console asap.

Is there something else I can do to inspect and 'check out' the image once it's pulled down?

Comment: If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in your Dockerfile, the `docker run ... sh` command you show will work.  As it is the `sh` is getting passed as an argument to `botnet`.

Comment: so i'll need to change the dockerfile, publish back to ACR and test again? Is that what you mean?

Comment: You should be able to `docker build && docker run` locally without pushing in between.

Comment: Also one issue that could be different between your local and CI environments, is how folder volumes are handled. Ideally, you want to be able to reproduce the problem locally instead of debugging online. If you have volumes in your docker compose, try to remove them or otherwise modify them to see if they are the cause.